# Qt Creator Android c++ code problem with boost

Tags: android, c++, boost

I am creating a TV application in Qt C++ with QML for Android. I have tested my desktop application in Qt and now I want to port it to android to be able to install it on tV. I have a problem with include boost. How to add boost library to the project?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

Has anyone also had a problem with this? And do you have any advice on porting files from Desktop to Adroid?
Two things from CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(AndroidTVApp PRIVATE
    Qt6::Core
    Qt6::Gui
    Qt6::Qml
    Qt6::Quick
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)

target_include_directories(AndroidTVApp PRIVATE
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/boost_1_84_0"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/boost_1_84_0/libs/asio"
)
```